# How save Facebook user display picture to the disk Without using file_get_contents()`?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

Hello I am trying to get the user profile picture and then merge into an existing image as per my Facebook app requirement. For that I need to check its mime time etc. But I am having difficulty in retrieving and saving the picture.

```
        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $user = $facebook -> getUser();
        if ($user) {
            $user_profile = $facebook -> api('/me');
        }

        //User Info. Variables:
        try {
            $userPpicture = $user_profile[picture];
            }
```

Now we I have retrieved this I want to save this image on disk so I could check its mime time etc. for further processing, how can I achieve this?

**p.s. due to my hosting server restrictions I can’t use the function `file_get_contents()`. So I need a solution except this.**

Kindly help.
thank-you.

---

**cURL try:**

```
    //Create image instances
        $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$userId}/picture?type=large";
        $dpImage = 'temp/' . $userId . '_dpImage_' . rand().'.jpg';
        echo $dpImage;

        function get_data($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            $timeout = 5;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        $returned_content = get_data($url);
        file_put_contents($dpImage, $returned_content);
        echo "Type: " . exif_imagetype($dpImage);
```

getting this error while checking the mime type of the image:
`Notice: exif_imagetype(): Read error! in`

Comment: @Baba: no `fopen` is also disabled. any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you allowed to use CURL ?

If so, just follow http://phpsense.com/2007/php-curl-functions/

Comment: Ive updated my code with my try with cURL, which i belive isnt working correctly, kindly have a look.

Comment: Kindly have a _debug_ yourself, please. var_dump the return value, see if there’s actually a file written to your server, check relevant function return values, … EDIT: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION might be missing.